# Add Component to GameObject that is locally safed

Tags: unity-game-engine, components

I want to safe a configurable joint as local variable, destroy it than (do stuff) add the configurable joint.

```
        Joint joint = outsideBodyPart.GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
        Destroy(outsideBodyPart.GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>());
        Debug.Log("do Stuff");
        outsideBodyPart.AddComponent<ConfigurableJoint>() = joint;
```

That doesnt't work, any suggestions friends?

Comment: wouldn't disabling/enabling the component be enough instead of destroying and adding?

Answer (score 0):

You are already saving the Joint in a variable so use it instead of calling it every time.

also, why do you use the `Joint` variable type when you want the `ConfigurableJoint` component?

```
    ConfigurableJoint joint = outsideBodyPart.GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
    Destroy(outsideBodyPart.GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>());
    Debug.Log("do Stuff");
    outsideBodyPart.AddComponent(typeof(ConfigurableJoint)) as ConfigurableJoint
```